# Time series prediction on web login timestamp

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression, data-science

If I have to build a time series prediction model and all I have is a sequence of timestamps of a user when he logs in to a site, how do you model that?.

Here is the first few rows of the data. I have got this as a Pandas Series.

```
0   2012-03-01 00:05:55
1   2012-03-01 00:06:23
2   2012-03-01 00:06:52
3   2012-03-01 00:11:23
4   2012-03-01 00:12:47
5   2012-03-01 00:12:54
6   2012-03-01 00:16:14
7   2012-03-01 00:17:31
8   2012-03-01 00:21:23
9   2012-03-01 00:21:26
```

Now couple of questions:

1). How to Graph the user behavior on hourly basis when all i have is timestamps and no Y values or any other features

2). Build a model which fits this time series and predict for next two weeks.

There is no other features or variable given. Just login time for like 3 months everyday.

Answer (score 0):

In response to part 1.  I have done something similar and ran into the same problem.  I grouped the time series using epoch and loaded it into a dictionary.  From there I could work on the time series in hour chunks.  (data source is json)  Then you can convert it to a panda DataFrame and chart directly using matplotlib.  Since your data is already in panda, you could skip the data pull and edit initial loop to process your raw data.  I hope this helps.

```
for key in responseJson['All'].keys():
        t = time.strftime('%Y,%m,%d %H:00:00', time.gmtime(float(key) / 1000.0))
        h = responseJson['All'][key]
        word = t
        epochkey = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(t, '%Y,%m,%d %H:00:00')))

        if word not in dict:
            dict[word] = h
            epochdict[epochkey] = h
        else:
            dict[word] += h
            epochdict[epochkey] += h
```

Then I converted it to a panda DataFrame:

```
for row in epochdict:
        if(row[0] not in data):
            data[row[0]]={}
        data[str(row[0])][str(row[2])]=round(row[3],3)

            df=DataFrame(data).T.fillna(0)
```

This allowed me to plot hourly data based on the time series.